# Is java array with an element null is of length 1?

Tags: java, arrays

Below code:

```
int[][][] aT = { {{9, 4}, null},  {null},  {{1, 2, 3}} };
System.out.println(aT.length + " " + aT[1].length);  // 3 1
```

shows `aT[1].length` as `1`.

Is it not that, length will be counted only when you have an element of type `int[][]` at second index in the object pointed by `aT`? If yes, Why `aT[1]` that is  `null` is of length 1? Because `null` is not of type `int[][]`

Similar example:

```
MyType[] t = {null};
System.out.println(t.length); //1
```

For me `t.length` should be `1`, only when array has element like `{new MyType()}` or element is an instance of subtype of `MyType`, something like,

```
MyType[] t = {new MyType()};
System.out.println(t.length); //1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes.**

In fact, when you declare and initialize an array of object references, all the values inside it will be `null` by default. Remember that the length of an array will never vary, despite the contents (`null` elements) in the array. There's a difference between **length** and **size**, the length is how many elements can be stored in an array, while the size is the amount of *valid* elements in the array. Also, an array **is not** a list.

Example:

```
String[] stringArray = { null, null };
System.out.println(stringArray.length);
stringArray[0] = "hello";
stringArray[1] = "world";
System.out.println(stringArray.length);
```

Prints:

```
2
2
```

---

From [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html)(emphasis mine):

> **An array object contains a number of variables. The number of variables may be zero, in which case the array is said to be *empty***. (...) **If an array has n components, we say n is the length of the array**; the components of the array are referenced using integer indices from 0 to n - 1, inclusive
>
> (...)
>
> Once an array object is created, **its length never changes**.
>
> (...)
>
> An array is created by an array creation expression (§15.10.1) or an array initializer (§10.6)
>
> An array creation expression specifies the element type, the number of levels of nested arrays, and the length of the array for at least one of the levels of nesting. **The array's length is available as a final instance variable length.**
>
> **An array initializer creates an array and provides initial values for all its components**.
>
> (...)
>
> The length of the array to be constructed is equal to the number of variable initializers immediately enclosed by the braces of the array initializer. Space is allocated for a new array of that length. If there is insufficient space to allocate the array, evaluation of the array initializer completes abruptly by throwing an OutOfMemoryError. Otherwise, **a one-dimensional array is created of the specified length, and each component of the array is initialized to its default value**.
>
> (...)
>
> - The public final field `length`, which **contains the number of components of the array**. `length` may be positive or zero.

From here, you may understand the following:

- When you initialize an array, you have to define at least the length of the first level (a.k.a. dimension). If you have an array of a single level, then this length will be the length of the whole array.
- When the array is initialized, all its components (a.k.a. elements) are initialized with the default value of the type. For primitive types, it may be `0` or `false` (depends on the type). For object references, it's `null`.
- The length of an array represents how many components can have.
- An array has a fixed length. This length cannot be changed.

Again, the length of an array (how many components can store) **is not the same** as the size of an array (how many components that we consider proper values is storing at the moment).

Comment: But in second there are 2 strings, which is fine.  IN first case, `{null, null}` are not two strings. why 2 in first case?

Comment: @overexchange, "null" is certainly a valid instance for an object like a String.  It is, essentially, a String because it /behaves/ as it it can be cast to any reference type.

Comment: How `null` being casted to any reference type has anything to do with length of the array?

Comment: For your point: "*when you declare and initialize an array of object references, all the values inside it will be null by default.*" syntactically this is not possible, except mentioning as null(explicitly), may be you are trying to say: "When you declare and create and array of object", something like `MyType mt[][] = new MyType[1][2];`.

Comment: How to find size of an array?

Comment: @overexchange you need another variable called `size` that starts at `0` and increments or decrements when the array is modified, this is, when you add/remove an element. For such purpose, you have `ArrayList` class, where you can know the current size of the backed array but you won't be able to know its capacity (`array.length`).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, null can be considered an object of the array's type. Null can be a string, a Date, a JFrame, anything you want it to be.

Comment: Because `null`  can be cast to any reference type? java array is one example of  reference type.

Comment: `null` doesn't belong to an exact reference type. It's not like it can be *casted*.

Comment: String string = (String) null;